# What is in Nova's Google folder?

Tags: launcher

I just installed Nova launcher on my Android phone. When I installed it it created a Google folder with all my Google Apps in it. I accidentally deleted, but I want it back.

Can anyone tell me what apps were in it?

Is there any way for me to figure this out?